# bootstrap navigation pushes content down fix?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

bootstrap collapsed navigation pushes the content down when its opened. is there a solution for this?

I tried to make the

```
.navbar-collapsed ul{
  position: absolue; 
}
```

but that hasn't changed it

normal view
[image]

wrong stuff
[image]

Comment: Please add some minimal code, so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try position: absolute to the content rather than the navbar.